# How to keep new lines when outputting posts retrieved from Facebook using the Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Say for example the original post on facebook is as follows:

```
Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow
```

The array returned from the graph api will have the following data:

```
    [message] => Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow
```

So there are newlines within the returned array data but when I am echoing the data out I simply get `Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow`

Is there a straightforward way to keep the original structure of the post?

All I am doing to echo it is:

```
  echo "<div class=\"post\">".$user_feed['data'][$i]['message']."</div>\n";
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  echo "<div class=\"post\">".nl2br($user_feed['data'][$i]['message'])."</div>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried wrapping it in a

```
<pre>
```

tag (i.e. preformated). Or you could replace new lines with line-breaks

```
<br />
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, I actually have the full array at the bottom of my page wrapped in a `<pre>` tag which is probably why the newlines looked correct in that but genesis' answer did the trick.

Comment: No Problem. I didn't know there was the method nl2br().